# Bitnami/elestio production keycloak container error: Cannot login to admin console

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, bitnami

I have been trying to lauch a keycloak inside my EKS cluster for a week now. I tried the helm chart from bitnami and cannot login to the admin console. After that I also tried the keycloak image from elastio but i still cannot login to the admin console.
For both cases I can login to the dev environment but when i switch to prod then it always gives the following error:

`2023-10-31 14:20:28,761 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-5) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=************************************, clientId=security-admin-console, userId=331da466-7060-45bf-b3ca-94ff69d070, ipAddress=10.0.5.47, error=invalid_user_credentials, auth_method=openid-connect, auth_type=code, redirect_uri=http://********************************.amazonaws.com/admin/master/console/, code_id=08212e5b-625b-482e-b602-703b929cc9, username=test-admin`

I set up the admin user and password using env out of k8s secret and been able to use them for dev environment. Like this:

```
         env: 
            - name: KC_DB_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ .Values.secretName }}
                  key: kcUser
              
            - name: KC_DB_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ .Values.secretName }}
                  key: kcPassword
            - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-admin
                  key: kcAdminUser
            - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-admin
                  key: kcAdminPassword
```

Maybe someone can point out what did I do wrong here? Much appreciate for your helps!

Comment: You did not provide any realm configuration. Keycloak is NOT working without proper setup.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information that you have you may need to check several factors that are causing the error. For starters, check the logs for errors, kubectl logs -f <keycloak-pod-name> then see if there is any information that can lead you to the issue. Also check the compatibility of your keycloak and the kubernetes environment in prod since you mentioned that it works in dev. Lastly, you might want to see if there are any Network or Security constraints that could hinder communication.